# hibernate.cfg.xml- how to incorporate it

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm doing a course on Hibernate and JPA fundamentals and I can't seem to find any discussion forums or anything similar as part of the course, so asking here.

The instructor had me create a hibernate.cfg.xml file and told me to change the hibernateUtil.java class.  This is what the class looks like now

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();


    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try{
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        return 
                configuration.buildSessionFactory
                (new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                        applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).
                        build());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Service factory creation failed");
    }
}
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where hibernate.cfg.xml is being used here.  THere is a simple application class being used to test this
    public class Application {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

In fact I even removed the hibernate.cfg.xml from source/main/properties and re-ran this (Ctrl-F11 in eclipse) and I didn't see any problems, ie no errors in the console.

So what changes need be made to the HibernateUtil class to use hibernate.cfg.xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some way to use `hibernate.cfg.xml`. It is slightly depends of Hibernate version.

You have

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
```

if you do

```
configuration.configure();
```

Hibernate will read `hibernate.cfg.xml`

To build a session factory, this is pretty enough:

```
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

You can do, of course, something like this:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();

return configuration.buildSessionFactory
        (new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).
                build());
```

You need this `applySettings(configuration.getProperties())`, only if you have properties in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`. But this code will work only with Hibernate 4. Hibernate 5 will lost mapping classes which it will get by `configuration.configure()`.

`hibernate.cfg.xml` should be in the root of the `src` folder or, if you use the maven build, in the `resources` folder (not `properties`). Anyway, after rebuild (refresh), it will be in the root of the build folder (`bin`, `build`).

Comment: Looks like the crux of it was I'm using Hibernate 5.2 and the course material might have been written with Hib 4.x.  Your solution of just using configuration.configure() is very simple and served the purpose for me.

Comment: @ChuckLeviton Hibernate 5 has its own bootstrap API, you can use it in more complex situations. You can consider to accept the answer, if you think it is the correct one.